# Detect combination of keys pressed in PyGtk3 Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk, pygobject

I want to detect when CTRL + Q are pressed and then perform an action.
Now, I have code to detect if one key is pressed, but not a combination.

Actually, my function is:

```
def on_key_press_event(self, widget, event):
    keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    print("Key %s (%d) pulsada" % (keyname, event.keyval))
    if keyname ==  "q":
        print (event.state)
        if event.state == "CONTROL_MASK":
            print ("controlcu")
    if keyname == "Escape":
        self.entrada.set_text("")
    if keyname == "Return":
        self.button1.clicked()
        self.entrada.set_text("")
```

As you can see I tried with the "if keyname == 'Escape'" thing. I can find only things for PyGtk2 but no PyGtk3. Thanks for your help!

+info: Some things are in spanish: pulsada = pressed; controlcu = controlQ; entrada = entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare names use the actual keyval/modifier. Some docs:
https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.do_key_press_event

Then here are the `Gdk.KEY_*` constants for `event.keyval`:
 https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/constants.html#details

And the modifiers for `event.state`: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/flags.html#Gdk.ModifierType

(FYI it is not called pygtk3)

Comment: Thanks, I used three variables that saves the keys pressed. When key is pressed, it stores it, and when key is released, it erases it. But with your method is easier. Sorry for my bad english, and thanks for the "It's not called Pygtk, I didn't knew

Answer (score 0):

In order to check key modifiers, use

```
is_ctrl_presset = bool(state & Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK)
```

Where & is the bitwise operattor